# Replacement for descendant-or-self

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I have a xpath `$x/descendant-or-self::*/@y` which I have changed to `$x//@y` as it improved the performance.
Does this change have any other impact?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [W3C XPath Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#abbrev), // is short-hand for /descendant-or-self::node()/, so that is a slight difference. But since attributes can only occur on elements, I think this replacement is safe.

That might also explain why you see a performance boost, since MarkLogic will need to worry less whether there really are elements in between.

HTH!